# How to use L'Hospital's rule for abstract functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

It is known that $f(x)$ has a first-order continuous derivative in a neighborhood of point `x = 0` and $f(0) f^{\prime}(0) \neq 0$. When $h \rightarrow 0$,then $a f(h)+b f(2 h)-f(0)=o(h)$.I want to calculate the limit of the abstract function $\frac{a f(h)+b f(2 h)-f(0)}{h}$ by using L'Hospital's rule:
$\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{a f(h)+b f(2 h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{a f^{\prime}(h)+2 b f^{\prime}(2 h)}{1}=(a+2b) f^{\prime}(0)$

```
Limit[(a*f[h] + b*f[2 h] - f[0])/h, 
 h -> 0, Analytic->True]
```

But the above methods can not get the desired results, what should I do to get the correct results?

Comment: Are you sure your maths is correct? I don't think the numerator limits to zero, in general.

Comment: Try for instance with **Limit[(a f[h] + h f[2 h] - a f[0])/h, h -> 0, Analytic -> True]** which has the numerator $\to 0$ as **h** $\to 0$.

Comment: @mikado Thank you for your guidance, I have updated the details of the question.

Comment: @Cesareo I have added the full details.. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'Hospital's rule is applicable if the  Limit would give a singular expression `0/0`

Try

```
Limit[(a*f[h] + b*f[2 h] - (a + b) f[0])/h, h -> 0, Analytic -> True]
(*(a + 2 b) Derivative[1][f][0]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only if $ a f(h)+b f(2 h)-f(0)$ is an infinitive that tends to zero, we can use the  L'Hospital's rule.

Because when $h \rightarrow 0$,then $a f(h)+b f(2 h)-f(0)=o(h)$, so $(1-a-b) f(0)=0$. And because $f(0) f^{\prime}(0) \neq 0$, $a+b=1$.

```
Limit[(a f[h] + b f[2 h] - f[0])/h, h -> 0, Assumptions -> a + b == 1,
  Analytic -> True]
```

Comment: Your first conclusion is wrong: I would expect `f[0] - a f[h]-b f[2 h]== o[h]` which leads to `(1-a-b) f[0]==0`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, because $f(0) f^{\prime}(0) \neq 0$, $f(0)  \neq 0$ and $(1-a-b)=0$. I need to think about it again.